# How to set color to json array in mainactivity java using if condition

Tags: android, arrays, json, colors

I have a json file [{name:dd,sname:f,add:xzxx},{name:dd,sname:f,add:xzxx},{name:dd,sname:f,add:xzxx},{name:dd,sname:t,add:xzxx},{name:dd,sname:t,add:xzxx},name:dd,sname:t,add:xzxx}..and so on.
I want to display the output in android such that if sname:f then the lsitview color should be red else any color
Any help..
My output has 3 columns Name,SName,Add which displays the json in listview which displays the json data.I want an if loop for the json array "sname"

Answer (score 0):

1. Parse the JSON array and store it in an `ArrayList`.
2. Pass the `ArrayList` to your custom adapter.
3. Toggle the view in the `getview` method of your adapter.

Comment: I am getting the values but just wanna change the color of the json array "sname" using the if condition..and where to put the if condition..thnx

Comment: http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/01/android-async-listview-jee-and-restful.html

Comment: if condition inisde your adapter

Comment: can i give you my mainactivity.java code...maybe then you can help me a bit better madam..

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(content);
    JSONArray leaders= json.getJSONArray("rows");
    Log.d("leaders",leaders.toString());
    for(int i=0;i<leaders.length(); i++){
        JSONObject jsonas = leaders.JSONObject(i);
        String fname = jsonas.getString("Fname");
        Log.d("First Names",fname);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Just replace your key names and it works.

Comment: thnx parth..but I want to change the color of my listview based on the json array "sname"..